# Compare string variable to array value drupal 7

Tags: arrays, string, drupal-7, strcmp

I have taxonomy terms using taxonomy_term_load($term->tid) and then I have a text field value stored in variable named $session_company. Now I need to compare the values of this field variable to one of taxonomy terms value. I am using following code but result is always false. Please advise what I am doing wrong here:

```
$employee_info_voc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('some_vocab');
    $employee_info_tree = taxonomy_get_tree($employee_info_voc->vid);
    $employee_list = array();
        if(isset($current_user->field_company_session['und'][0]['value'])){
            foreach ($employee_info_tree as $term) {
                $employee_data = taxonomy_term_load($term->tid);
                $employee_company = $employee_data->field_emp_company_name['und'][0]['value'];
                $session_company = $current_user->field_company_session['und'][0]['value'];
                if($session_company === $employee_company){

                    $employee_list[] = $term->tid;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Install devel module and before if() block dump your data. dpm($session_company, 'session company'); dpm($employee_company, 'employee company); now you can see what you compare

Comment: Can't believe I was overlooking a typo. Thanks @lamp5  :)